# Error:(105) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml

i got 3 errors on my projects :

First and Second Error :

First: Error:(105) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

```
<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/profileListView"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorRipple" />
```

Second Error : Error:(105) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

```
<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/profileListView"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorRipple" />
```

Third Errror :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: I think the package name is wrong for the Floating Action Button, check it and change the package name accordingly

Comment: Try the basic FAB  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width=""
        android:layout_height="" />

Answer (score 1):

The direct errors indicate undeclared namespace prefixes.  Make sure you have the following on the root element of your XML file:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

(Or choose one of `app` and `fab` and use consistently.)

***Note, however, that `com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton` is deprecated***.

You really should use **[FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)** instead.

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: @DritonSopa: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Comment: You should accept this! It worked for me!